# How to rent in France before applying for a visa

Tags: visa, france, rental

To apply for a 1-year visitor's visa, you need to provide proof of where you'll be staying for your entire year in France, but to rent an apartment, you need to provide proof of French residency status.  I was thinking of going to France for about a month, to start leasing a flat, and then present that lease when applying for the visa, but without French residency or a contract to work for a French company, how can I rent a place?

How do you overcome the problem of putting the cart before the horse (without finding someone there willing to lie for you)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that you have to provide _proof of French residency status_ to rent an apartment. See https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1169

Comment: @audionuma: Thank you!  I had read about that "proof of French residency status" requirement on some random website for expats, but thank you for pointing me to the authoritative answer.

Comment: @audionuma You should expand your comment into an answer.